# trying to generate random passwords with "-" in between

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()?"
passlen = 4
p = "".join(random.sample(s,passlen))
p2 = "".join(random.sample(s,passlen))
print(p,"-",p2)
```

This is my code. But when i run it get something like this: RJ9e - zN0P
I do not need the spaces in between. What am i missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: That's part of the `print` - the `sep` between parameters is `' '` by default. Try `print(p, '-', p2, sep='')` or e.g. `print('-'.join((p, p2)))`.

Comment: This would be nicer: `print('%s-%s' % (p, p2))`

Comment: Note that you can simply do the following: `p = "".join(random.sample(s,8))` and then `p = p[:4] + "-" + p[4:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `print(p,"-",p2)` will print spaces between its arguments, better use `print("{}-{}".format(p, p2))`.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

just concat all string into single string using '+' operator

```
import random
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()?"
passlen = 4
p = "".join(random.sample(s,passlen))
p2 = "".join(random.sample(s,passlen))
print(p+"-"+p2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of print. You need to concat password into single variable like that:
`password = '%s-%s' % (p, p2)`